# Splitting a column and adding text value to the numerical value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database called `Customer` within it I have a table called `Product` and within this product table I have a column called `Class` and `Client`. Now this class column has single values and  numerous values in the column separated by a `';'` it looks like this:

```
Class            Client
1                a
5                b
6                c
8;4              d
7                e
2                f
1                g
3                h
2;1              i
8;5;9;10         j
10               k
```

what I am trying to accomplish is separate all of the classes by client and apply a text value to the class. For example here is the text value I want to correspond with the numerical values under the class column. (Unfortunately these text values are not in the database and I don't have permission to create a table).

```
Class         Product 
1             cat
2             dog 
3             bird
4             fish
5             tree
6             car
7             desk
8             TV
9             door
10            bike
11            radio
12            disk
```

This is what the desired output would look like.

```
Client      Class
a           cat
b           tree
c           car
d           TV
d           fish
e           desk
f           dog 
g           cat
h           bird
i           dog 
i           cat
j           tree
j           TV
j           door
j           bike
k           bike
```

How would I do this? I am using Microsoft SQL Server.

Thank you!

Comment: Stop storing delimited data in your RDBMS; that is the *real* answer. Considering that you *should* have foreign keys on your data, you shouldn't have been able to `INSERT` a value like `'8;5;9;10'` at all. It's the wrong data type, and no rows with that value `'8;5;9;10'` exist in your other table.

Comment: I wish I had control over how the data is stored, its out of my scope of authority

Answer (score 2):

You can use `split_string()` and a derived table:

```
select t.client, v.classname
from t cross apply
     split_string(t.class, ';') s left join
     (values ('1', 'cat'),
             ('2', 'dog'),
             . . .
     ) v(class, classname)
     on t.class = v.class
```